# SAS intersect with date values

Tags: sql, sas

I have two tables, one that was created using a connection to teradata and other one that was created importing an excel file.

I need to find the records that are on one table but not on the other given three of the fields. The first two are returning what i would expect but when i add the third field which is a date field then none of the records match. Wen i look into the tables i see that the two dates are identical but somehow SAS does not consider them to be identical.

My code looks like this:

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE fields_that_do_not_match AS
        SELECT /*FIRST TWO FIELDS*/ date_a  FROM table_a
            EXCEPT
        SELECT /*FIRST TWO FIELDS*/ date_b FROM table_b;
QUIT;
```

Is there something else i should be considering for comparing dates?
When i see the properties of the date fields both are on `DATE9.` format, are of numerical type and have 8 bytes in length. Both of the dates show `14FEB2022` when i query the table but i don't know if some of the tables have aditional information that is not being displayed due to the format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you run this on both datasets?  `data _null_; set [table]; put [datefield] 16.8; run;` (if you have a lot of records, use `obs=` to limit this to only a small number).  I think there might be decimal values in your dates in one or the other.

Comment: Try rounding the dates to integer values and then compare them.

Comment: @Tom i added `INT(DATE_A)` and it worked thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the dates did not match was because one of them had decimal values and i needed to round the values. I added `INT(DATE_A)` and it worked after that.